# Checking in_array from db with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I to achieve checking roles using the following snippets? What I want to attain is to be able to authenticate user depending on assigned roles. `in_array()` not work for returned array.

Returned array is:

```
array (size=2) 0 => object(stdClass)[40] public 'role' => string '2' (length=1) 1 => object(stdClass)[41] public 'role' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Data:

```
DB TABLE
id user_id role
1  4       2
2  4       5
```

Model

```
//get logged user roles
public function user_roles($id){
    $userDB  = $this->quickDB();
    $userdata = $userDB->query("SELECT role
                            FROM role_assignment
                            WHERE user_id = $id
                            ")->result();
    $userDB->close();
    return ($userdata);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function user_roles()
{
    $roles=$this->Master_model->user_roles('4');

    if (in_array("1", $roles)) 
    {
        echo "Admin<br>";
    }
    if (in_array("2", $roles)) 
    {
        echo "Teacher<br>";
    }
    if (in_array("5", $roles)) 
    {
        echo "Academic<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you having problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_array` in your code can't work. You need to make two changes.

First - change your DB output to array, now you are getting objetct:

```
$userdata = $userDB->query("SELECT role
                        FROM role_assignment
                        WHERE user_id = $id
                        ")->result_array();
```

Second - itterate through DB result and return modified array:

```
$user_roles = array();
foreach ($userdata as $val) {
    $user_roles[] = $val['role'];
}
return $user_roles;
```

Both changes are inside user_roles function in your model.

Comment: Thank you; but where to place second codes? If it returning $user_roles what are the uses of foreach?

Comment: But I changed $value['role'] to $val['role']